# Preg replace to add number

Tags: php, preg-replace

I try to find a way to add number to a pattern inside a XML.

String inside XML looks like :

> Blabla blabla ${bâtiment} : blabla

And I want at the end

> Blabla blabla ${bâtiment1} : blabla

I found something like this :

```
preg_replace('/\$\{(\w)\w+\}/', '\${\\1#' . $i . '}', $cloneXML);
```

But it doesn't work, the result contain only the first letter :

> Blabla blabla ${b1} : blabla

I don't find something to get all the word :/

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PCRE modifier `/u` for unicode and put brackets around the reference in the replacement, so that it doesn't get concatenated with the number from your variable `$i`. Also your regular expression did not catch whole words, so maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php

$cloneXML = 'Blabla blabla ${bâtiment} : blabla';
$i = 42;

print preg_replace('/\$\{(\w*)\}/u', '{${1}' . $i . '}', $cloneXML);
// => Blabla blabla {bâtiment42} : blabla
```

See output: [3v4l.org/k8mIQ](https://3v4l.org/k8mIQ)

Comment: When one uses `\n` backreference, there is no need to wrap the number with curly braces as there can only be 1 to 9 backreferences defined with the backslash+number.

Comment: I didn't know that, but how comes this is not working then: https://3v4l.org/JN78s (using `\\1` instead of `${1}`)

Comment: It works well thank !